# 2D X-Ray Imaging of Surface Mounted Capacitors

Tags: capacitor, x-rays

Will the imaging yield sufficient details which would outline say an embedded antenna ? Suppose for the sake of the argument the antenna is hidden. Even though it's not. Lastly there will be no electrical transmission through the chip that contain these surface mounted capacitors.

Comment: Conductors will stand out clearly

Comment: A grid-dip wire may also detect a tiny piece of metal. It would be by capacitive effect, not electromagnetic.

Comment: @Sparky. Could you explain in layman's language what do you mean by a grid-dip wire ? Are you saying its possible to detect the antenna by using a grid-dip wire ?

Comment: It is ancient technology, but it is actually a small wire tied to an RF oscillator that reacts to any metal or if a plate, it reacts to mass-someone stepping on the plate, shoes or not. By keeping the wire tiny, it is affected only by tiny pieces of metal or larger. The higher the frequency, the closer it must be to the metal. At 1 to 5 GHZ, a 1/4 inch piece of wire could be picked up as a change in tone. It is a metal detector at heart but designed for tiny pieces using capacitance loading for detection.

Comment: The original grip-dip wire or coil was used to find the resonate frequency of RF coils back in the days of tubes, when coils were large. The 'dip' would occur as current consumption on the oscillator driving the test wire would peak or dip, depending on resonance or anti-resonance.

Answer (score 0):

A microfocus xray image (the standard thing for imaging PCBs to check soldering) can see down to a scale to make the bond wires at least somewhat visible, so any feature above that size should be easily visible.

A cap is not the obvious component if you were seeking to hide an antenna structure, and inductor is a much more obvious contender as the things tend to radiate anyway.

Given a sufficiently high operating frequency it might be possible to make a on chip aerial structure either in the metalisation or possibly even in the doped silicon and especially in the Si case, good luck seeing that. Efficiency would likely suck however, and the frequency would have to be high enough that penetration would be poor. This is the sort of thing you see in THz imagers and the like, expensive tech and possibly not that compatible with standard cell libraries.